# Module '"axios"' has no exported member 'AxiosRequestConfig'. Did you mean to use 'import AxiosRequestConfig from "axios"' instead?

Tags: typescript, axios

I have this axiosInstance:

```
 import axios from "axios";
 import { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";

  const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.example.com",
  });

  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
   return config;
  },
  (error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
   }
  );

   axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
   return response;
   },
    (error) => {
   return Promise.reject(error);
    }
   );

    export default axiosInstance;
```

in IDE I am getting the error:

```
Module '"axios"' has no exported member 'AxiosRequestConfig'. Did you mean to use 'import AxiosRequestConfig from "axios"' instead?
```

I tried in tsconfig.json:

```
"moduleResolution": "node",

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

None works

Comment: This problem has been mentioned before in axios [Issue#5573](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5573). Does the link work with your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get autocomplete - there should be no need to explicitly import `AxiosRequestConfig`, Typescript will pull it automatically, and you will still get autocomplete in your code editor:

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {
   return config;
  },
  (error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
   }
  );
```

P.S. And for the future, I'd advise to combine 2 imports like this:
`import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from "axios";`

P.P.S. It's more like a comment, but I don't have enough reputation to leave those

Comment: const { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } = axios; this one worked. But I don't know whether it is a correct way of doing it

Comment: @AdinaiZhamangulova, nope, it's not correct, you're desctructuring types as regular variables. curios how it is working for you, lol. 

try `import type { AxiosError, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';`

Comment: @AdinaiZhamangulova, btw which versions of axios and typescript you are using?

Comment: "axios": "^1.6.0",
   "vuex": "^4.1.0",